# Get resolver default value from symfony2 custom form type defined as service

Tags: forms, symfony

Suppose I have custom symfony2 form type defined as a service, I want to get my defined default value in this custom form type in my controller.

For example I want to filter my data based on value selected in this custom form type.

I already check the AbstractType class but there is no function to get the resolver default value defined from my custom form type.

I don't want using entity to store this simple data, it's just 3 row of data.

```php
<?php 

namespace Jariff\AdminBundle\Form\CustomType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class JariffSalutationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'empty_value' => '---',
            'choices'     => array(
                'Mr.'  => 'Mr.',  
                'Mrs.' => 'Mrs.', 
                'Ms.'  => 'Ms.',
            )));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'jariff_salutation';
    }
}
```

Service definition

```yaml
services:

    jariff_type_salutation:

        class: Jariff\AdminBundle\Form\CustomType\JariffSalutationType

        tags:

            - { name: form.type, alias: jariff_salutation }
```

Example usage

```php
$salutation = $this->get('jariff_type_salutation');
$entities = $em->getRepository('JariffMemberBundle:Member')->findBy(array('salutation' => $salution[1]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. You should instead define the salutation choices as a parameter (`salutations`) in your config.yml and pass this parameter to your form type following [this recipe](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service). Then, in your controller, retrieve the array of choices with (following your example usage):

```
$this->container->getParameter('salutations')[1];
```

You could also add a `public static function getSalutations()` to your form type which returns the array of choices and call it in `setDefaultOptions`:

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'empty_value' => '---',
    'choices'     => self::getSalutations()
));
```

Comment: Interesting answer, writing this 3 line of data in form type and in config file has same effort. Although new programmer in team need more files to be opened when inspecting this function. Also I rarely check my config yml except for installing new bundle or initial project setup. I'm still waiting for less effort solution before marking your answer. Thanks.